# the logout component not rendering after the authenticated is turned to true this is similar code as from react-router docs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I just tried to build  the react-router docs ex on browser but there is problem in `AuthButton` component it isn't showing `signOut` button when the `isAuthenticated` turns true

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link,
    Redirect,
    useHistory,
    useLocation,
} from 'react-router-dom';



export default function AuthExample() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <AuthButton />

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to='/public'>Public Page</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to='/protected'>Protected Page</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/public'>
                        <PublicPage />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path='/login'>
                        <LoginPage />
                    </Route>
                    <PrivateRoute path='/protected'>
                        <ProtectedPage />
                    </PrivateRoute>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

const fakeAuth = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    authenticate(cb) {
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = true;
        setTimeout(cb, 100); // fake async
    },
    signout(cb) {
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = false;
        setTimeout(cb, 100);
    },
};
function AuthButton() {
    let history = useHistory();

    return fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <p>
            Welcome!{' '}
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    fakeAuth.signout(() => history.push('/'));
                }}>
                Sign out
            </button>
        </p>
    ) : (
        <p>You are not logged in.</p>
    );
}


function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={({ location }) =>
                fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
                    children
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: '/login',
                            state: { from: location },
                        }}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );
}

function PublicPage() {
    return <h3>Public</h3>;
}

function ProtectedPage() {
    return <h3>Protected</h3>;
}

function LoginPage() {
    let history = useHistory();
    let location = useLocation();

    let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: '/' } };
    let login = () => {
        fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
            history.replace(from);
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <p>You must log in to view the page at {from.pathname}</p>
            <button onClick={login}>Log in</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It looks like your `AuthButton` is not connected to your authentication so it won't change until it is connected to the authentication. Trying using context to allow it to receive `isAuthenticated`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not updating is because it doesn't know to update. You change the route but `AuthButton` doesn't know to re-render based on the route you need to pass it a prop so that it knows when to update. I refactored your code to incorporate using [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). By using hooks you can store `isAuthenticated` in local state in `AuthExample` via `useState`.

From `AuthExample`, pass down the state value for `isAuthenticated` as a prop to `AuthButton`. If the prop changes, `AuthButton` will detect it and this will trigger a re-render of `AuthButton` and reflect the correct component structure you are looking for. See below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  useHistory,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function AuthExample() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const fakeAuth = {
    isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
    authenticate(cb) {
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = true;
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
      setTimeout(cb, 100); // fake async
    },
    signout(cb) {
      setIsAuthenticated(false);
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = false;
      setTimeout(cb, 100);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <AuthButton fakeAuth={fakeAuth} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />

        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/public">Public Page</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/public">
            <PublicPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login">
            <LoginPage fakeAuth={fakeAuth} />
          </Route>
          <PrivateRoute path="/protected" fakeAuth={fakeAuth}>
            <ProtectedPage />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function AuthButton(props) {
  const { fakeAuth, isAuthenticated } = props;
  let history = useHistory();

  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <p>
      Welcome!{" "}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          fakeAuth.signout(() => history.push("/"));
        }}
      >
        Sign out
      </button>
    </p>
  ) : (
    <p>You are not logged in.</p>
  );
}

function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  const { fakeAuth } = rest;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

function PublicPage() {
  return <h3>Public</h3>;
}

function ProtectedPage() {
  return <h3>Protected</h3>;
}

function LoginPage(props) {
  const { fakeAuth } = props;

  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();

  let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
  let login = () => {
    fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
      history.replace(from);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You must log in to view the page at {from.pathname}</p>
      <button onClick={login}>Log in</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can also see a working example [in this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-burnell-69wq0?file=/src/App.js). There are a few ways to do this but hooks make it easy to manipulate state values to update functional components without having to make them class components. This way also keeps most of your code intact as is just adding a few checks for when `isAuthenticated` is updated.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in rendering process. 
In my opinion,  if you put the sub-functions in to the exported function, this problem may solve.

If the problem won't solve, try the class base component for handling this rendering process.

wish you success

Comment: this should be as a comment not as an answer

Comment: It's your opinion, tnx

Comment: @artm what Skoltz is saying is that the content isn't sufficient as an answer because it doesn't contain a real solution, code or references, rather it is giving brief advice with a vague solution. In the future be sure to include code and or references so that the solution is more specific and less an abstract idea.

Comment: Thank you, I remember it for next time